# Why are mussels called 淡菜

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

The name 淡菜 would suggest a meaning like "bland vegetable" or something like that. Why are mussels called 淡菜?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

淡菜 is only the name for **dried** mussels or **dried** sea mussels.

**汉语大词典**'s entry for 淡菜 says:

> 贻贝的肉经烧煮曝洒而成的干制食品。味佳美, 以煮晒时不加盐, 故名。

So 淡 comes from the fact that 不加盐 (salt is not added).

菜 must be for the fact that it is a *dish* and not because it is a vegetable.